# Getting an ActiveRecord::Statement Invalid Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Not sure what I'm missing here with my Rails app. I have set up "posts" and "projects" in very similar manner. However, when I click on my "Projects" link I get an ActiveRecord::Statement Invalid error. No such problem with the Posts index page. Specifically the message for the Projects index page is:

"SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: created_by: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"  ORDER BY created_by DESC"

I know this can often result from misnaming things - especially plural vs singular needing to match up. Still the two models and controllers look effectively the same to me - only small differences. So I can't locate where the problem is.

Here's my controller page:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :find_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @projects = Project.all.order("created_by DESC")
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new project_params

    if @project.save
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Nice work! Successfully saved!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show

  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @project.update project_params
      redirect_to @project, notice: "Nice work! That project was successfully updated!"
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @project.destroy
    redirect_to projects_path
  end

  private

  def find_project
    @project = Project.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def project_params
    params.require(:project).permit(:title, :description, :link, :slug)
  end
end
```

And here's the projects index.html.erb page:

```
<h1 id="page_title">Projects</h1>

<div id="posts_wrapper" class="skinny_wrapper">
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <div class="post">
            <p class="date"><%= project.created_at.strftime('%A, %B, %d') %></p>
            <h2><a href="#"><%= link_to project.title, project %></a></h2>
            <hr>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

And here's my _create_projects.rb table info:

```
class CreateProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :projects do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :link

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
```

And I have this as well:

```
class AddSlugToProjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :projects, :slug, :string
    add_index :projects, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have `created_by` column in `projects` table?

Comment: I'll add the table column info to my original post.

Comment: Ahh, yes There is no `created_by` column. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks! That was it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that `created_by` should be `created_at`

`created_at` and `updated_at` are the fields created in migration when you have

```
t.timestamps
```

in your migration file.

So change your `index` method

```
  def index
    @projects = Project.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end
```

Comment: Ahh! That's what I missed. My posts controller had that correct, but not my projects controller. Thanks so much. I made that edit and now it works. Much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: created_by: SELECT "projects".*
>   FROM "projects" ORDER BY created_by DESC

The error clearly tell that there is no column called `created_by` in the `projects` table.

You need to generate a migration to add `created_by` column to the `projects` table.

```
rails g migration add_created_by_to_projects created_by:string
```

and then do `rake db:migrate`